# ansible problem with single quote, double quote in uri body

Tags: ansible, urlencode, quotes, double-quotes

I have a problem with the correct syntax to address an API with absolutely don't understands any json arguments.
In the body must be exactly one value in this form '["XXXX"]' so that it works.

```
 - uri:
     url: "{{ AssociatePolicies_url }}"
     method: POST
     return_content: yes
     validate_certs: no
     body_format: form-urlencoded
     body: 
       apiKey: "{{ apiKey }}"
       ASSIGNED_POLICIES: '["XXXX"]'
       RESOURCEID: "{{ resourceId }}"
       RUNCOMPCHECK_STATUS: true
     headers:
       Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
```

but when I pass the value now as variable i don't get it in the correct form

```
---
- name: Post to API
  hosts: KingKong
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    policygroup: 
      - XXXX
#      - YYYY
#      - ZZZZ
  tasks:
  - uri:
      url: "{{ AssociatePolicies_url }}"
      method: POST
      return_content: yes
      validate_certs: no
      body_format: form-urlencoded
      body: 
        apiKey: "{{ apiKey }}"
        ASSIGNED_POLICIES:  "'["{{ item }}"]'"
        RESOURCEID: "{{ resourceId }}"
        RUNCOMPCHECK_STATUS: true
     headers:
       Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
   with_items: "{{ policygroup }}"
```

Is the response: Error while parsing ASSIGNED_POLICIES json data

After various approaches I don't get any closer to the result:

```
ASSIGNED_POLICIES: "\'[{{ item }}]\'"       is the format '[XXXX]
ASSIGNED_POLICIES: \'["{{ item }}"]\'       is the format \\'[\"XXXX\"]\\'
ASSIGNED_POLICIES: "\'[\"{{ item }}\"]\'"   is the format '[\"XXXX\"]'
ASSIGNED_POLICIES: "\'["{{ item }}"]\'"     playbook error
ASSIGNED_POLICIES: "\'[{{ \" }}{{ item }}{{\"}}]\'" is the format '[ }}{{ item }}{{]'"}]
```

where I get almost closer to the format is:

```
ASSIGNED_POLICIES: "\'['{{ item }}']\'" is the format "'['XXXX']'"
```

but with single quote in front anb ack of XXXX but there must be double quote.

Maybe one of you has a creative idea

Comment: How are you actually managing to get an item looping over a string ? AFAIK the above code with the given data will lead to an error (something like "list expected got string"). Can you double check and make your example [MCVE](/help/mcve) ? The way you declare your data might have an impact on the result you get.

Comment: Meanwhile if I correctly inferred your problem between the lines, the following might solve your issue => `ASSIGNED_POLICIES:  "{{ [item] | to_json }}"`

Comment: Thx for your response.. The problem is that it needs exactly this format '['XXXX']'. So quote, square brackets, double quote, some digest, double quote, square brackets.

Comment: This does not make any sense or you failed to. The only relevant content is what is inside the outer quotes in your example (its pure yaml syntax). What you are showing us is a string representation of a json list. Enclosing it between between single quotes or double quotes will only change the way you have to eventually escape characters in your string. `to_json` simply takes care of doing all this for you from a yaml representation of your data.

Comment: With your suggestion it also only sends XXXX, so the text part '["...."]' is missing.
My problem is that the API expects a pure text string '["XXXX"]' and I can't manage to generate it when I build a loop.
I tried to escape it but it always got \ in the string (see above). It is never exactly '["XXXX"]'.
I will probably set up my play in such a way that I build several task.yml (see above with the correct Form) with works and loop this task.yml .
Merci pour votre temps

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected my source code above and post below what I get back as a response.
What i see in see response:

```
 "content": "{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Error while parsing ASSIGNED_POLICIES json data.\",\"errorcode\":\"JSON_PARSE_ERROR\"}}\n"
```

and the wrong format:

```
"ASSIGNED_POLICIES": "'[XXXX]'"
```

It is missing double quote in front and behind XXXX.
this must be the correct post

```
"ASSIGNED_POLICIES": "'["XXXX"]'"
```

.

```
{
"changed": false,
"_ansible_verbose_always": true,
"result_4": {
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "changed": false,
    "results": [
        {
            "content_length": "104",
            "status": 200,
            "cookies": {
                "opmcsrfcookie": "192d408c-be9b-42f7-985b-56360c06fdd7"
            },
            "set_cookie": "opmcsrfcookie=192d408c-be9b-42f7-985b-56360c06fdd7;path=/;Secure;priority=high",
            "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
            "elapsed": 0,
            "msg": "OK (104 bytes)",
            "content_type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            "date": "Wed, 16 Mar 2021 16:22:55 GMT",
            "x_frame_options": "deny",
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "x_xss_protection": "1",
            "url": "https://https://AssociatePolicies_url",
            "changed": false,
            "x_content_type_options": "nosniff",
            "connection": "close",
            "content": "{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Error while parsing ASSIGNED_POLICIES json data.\",\"errorcode\":\"JSON_PARSE_ERROR\"}}\n",
            "failed": false,
            "json": {
                "error": {
                    "errorcode": "JSON_PARSE_ERROR",
                    "message": "Error while parsing ASSIGNED_POLICIES json data."
                }
            },
            "item": 301,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "directory_mode": null,
                    "force": false,
                    "remote_src": null,
                    "status_code": [
                        200
                    ],
                    "follow": false,
                    "owner": null,
                    "body_format": "form-urlencoded",
                    "client_key": null,
                    "group": null,
                    "use_proxy": true,
                    "unix_socket": null,
                    "unsafe_writes": null,
                    "setype": null,
                    "content": null,
                    "serole": null,
                    "follow_redirects": "safe",
                    "return_content": true,
                    "client_cert": null,
                    "body": {
                        "RUNCOMPCHECK_STATUS": true,
                        "RESOURCEID": "abcde",
                        "apiKey": "just_a_Key",
                        "ASSIGNED_POLICIES": "'[XXXX]'"
                    },
                    "url_username": null,
                    "src": null,
                    "dest": null,
                    "selevel": null,
                    "force_basic_auth": false,
                    "removes": null,
                    "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
                    "regexp": null,
                    "url_password": null,
                    "url": "https://AssociatePolicies_url",
                    "validate_certs": false,
                    "seuser": null,
                    "method": "POST",
                    "creates": null,
                    "headers": {
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
                    },
                    "delimiter": null,
                    "mode": null,
                    "timeout": 30,
                    "attributes": null,
                    "backup": null
                }
            },
            "redirected": false,
            "cookies_string": "opmcsrfcookie=192d408c-be9b-42f7-985b-56360c06fdd7"
        }
    ]
},
"_ansible_no_log": false
}
```